# Rotating multiple points at once in 2D

Tags: xna, c#, 2d, algorithm, rotation

I currently have an editor that creates shapes out of (X, Y) coordinates and then triangulate that to make up a shape of those points.

What will I have to do to rotate all of those points simultaneously? Say I click the screen in my editor, it locates the point where I've clicked and if I move the mouse up or down from that point it calculates rotation on X and Y axis depending on new position relevant to first position, say I move up 10 on the Y axis it rotates that way and the same way for X. Or simply, somehow to enter rotation degree: 90, 180, 270, 360, for example.

I use VertexPositionColor at the moment.

What are the best algorithms or methods that I can look at to rotate multiple points in 2D at once?

**Also:**

Since this is an editor I do now want to rotate it on the Matrix, so if I want to rotate the whole shape 180 degree that's the new "position" of all the points, so that's the new rotation = 0 for example. Later on I probably will use World Matrix rotation for this, but not now.

[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean by "rotation on X axis"? In 2D, you can only rotate anything around a *point*, not around a line.

Comment: @MartinSojka You have to specify the rotation axis in 2D as well. For example: Matrix worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationY(angle);

Comment: @Marton: What would a rotation by, say, 30 degrees around the Y axis in 2D exactly *mean* - where would the points end up? Remember that neither the points nor the axis can be located outside those two dimensions, neither pre nor post rotation.

Comment: @MartinSojka I think it would change just the X coordinate of the point. I might be wrong though, but I'm pretty sure it's a valid phrasing to say "rotate around the Y axis" in 2D.

Comment: By the way, we usually rotate about the Z axis in 2D.

Comment: @Marton: There is no Z axis in 2D. And if you change just the X coordinate, that's either scaling or movement, or a combination thereof.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6237/discussion-between-marton-and-martin-sojka)

Comment: 2D is just a 'special case' of 3D, in which an object can only translate along the XY plane and rotate along the Z axis. However you are right in saying that you need to specify a point in the plane to rotate about, the origin of rotation. If you use a matrix, first translate the entire object such that the origin of rotation is at (0,0,0) then apply a rotation matrix to all vertices. Finally apply the inverse translation. Your object should now have rotated in full :)

Comment: Blender 2d rotation for example, add a plane and press r and you rotate along the center point of the plane and the position of the mouse in the world, you get this kind of transformation. Since I said that I didn't want to rotate on the world matrix AT ALL, because if I start up with a rectangle, rotate it 45 degrees than it shouldn't be rotated by 45 degrees, it should be the new standard so to speak. All the points should move 45 degrees each and all the points end up 45 degrees rotated which also has rotated the entire shape.

Comment: So after rotation, the shapes world matrix rotation = 0 because the points have just moved. Later, when I use the shape for animation and etc World Matrix rotation will be more handy instead of rotating all the points.

Comment: So perhaps, the center point, and position where you clicked it and the position where you moved it make up an "angle", right? Is that data good enough to make a rotation?

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating things. For a rotation in 2D, you need a point (the point around which the rotation happens) and some way to specify the angle of rotation - examples would be an angle value, a complex number describing the rotation, or two directional vectors - one for the direction pre rotation, one for the direction post rotation. So far, I don't even see where your origin point is supposed to be located. On the one hand, you write something about clicking on the screen to locate the point; on the other hand, you bring Blender as an example, which *doesn't do that*.

Comment: Whoever claims that rotation in 2D occurs about an axis doesn't understand 2D planar spaces, and should educate themselves accordingly. You are either working in a 3D space with all points on single plane, or you are working in 2D space. There is a substantial conceptual difference. @Deukalion, which is it going to be? Depending on the answer, the appropriate matrix can be supplied.

Comment: I currently have a method that I can just enter an angle and all points are rotated along that. So to find an angle between 3 points  must be possible and which is what I'm after. Center point of the object, first position of the mouse where you've clicked and current position of the mouse.

Comment: @Deukalion, I know you've been trying hard to explain the configuration but I think a picture would paint a thousand words here. A quick MS paint diagram would probably get the question answered quickly -- just a thought. Mainly because you're talking about a number of different aspects to this.

Comment: I just updated it with a thousand words. Center Point, Start Point, Current Point. Grid and shape is from the editor.

Comment: Just to clear up things after the "no Z-axis in 2D" debate, here's an MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194912(v=xnagamestudio.10).aspx   Please notice that in this article, the RotatePoints method calls the Matrix.CreateRotationZ method. The description of said method is: "Creates a matrix that can be used to rotate a set of vertices around the z-axis. "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a center for rotation... in this case the box center..

then when you detect the mouse down you store vector (A) from the center to the mouse coords... this is your initial vector.... ans should store your shape rotation as initial rotation.

then while you move the mouse and it continues being down you calculate the second vector (B) from the center to the current mouse coords...

now you can calculate the angle between to vectors... as you should know it can be calculated normalizing the two vectors and calcultaing the dot product... so you get the cosine... now you get the angle with an arccosine function...

this angle should be added to the initial rotation of your shape... ans set the new rotation for your shape.

so you only have to build your transform matrix for your shape...

the easiest way is to store your vertex coords relative to the center of the shape, if you don't store that way you should get that points relative to it...

Your transform matrix should similar to this...

```
// Supposing your coords are absolute 
Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateTranslation( -Center )                       
                 * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation)
                 * Matrix.CreateTranslation (Center );

// Supposing your coords are relative, center is (0,0)
Matrix transform = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation)
```

You should realize that usually the right way is the easy way... you should use matrix transforms... I'd do something similar to this:

```
  class Bone2D {
      Vector2 Translation;
      float Rotation;
      float Scale;
      Bone Parent;
      Matrix Local { get { return Matrix.CreateScale(scale) 
                                * Matrix.CreateRotationZ(rotation)
                                * Matrix.CreateTranslation(translation); } }
      Matrix Absolute { get{ return (Parent == null) 
                                       ?  Local 
                                       : Parent.Absolute * Local; }}
  }

  class Shape : Bone2D {

      Vector2[] RelativeCoords;  // Relative to your shape center
      Vector2[] AbsoluteCoords { 
           get{ 
             return RelativeCoords.Select(r => Vector2.Transform(r, Absolute)
                                  .ToArray();
           } }
  }
```

This way the shape you show in your example, would have two bones...

1) the parent bone that translates the shape,

2) the shape that is a bone itself and can be rotated easily... or scaled or translated again relative to the parent bone of course...  ;)

This editor is quite old... I have a new version... but the video shows what you can achieve doing it right... http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=K9R5v5Va4CI#t=28s

I hope this to be useful... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generic and math-heavy answer ahead.

We have the following points:

Origin *O* = (*x*<sub>O</sub>, *y*<sub>O</sub>), the origin (or centre) of the object and the origin point for our rotation.

Starting point *S* = (*x*<sub>S</sub>, *y*<sub>S</sub>), the point at which the mouse was pressed down and/or the mouse was when the rotation was initiated.

Current (mouse) point *M* = (*x*<sub>M</sub>, *y*<sub>M</sub>), the point the mouse is at right now during the rotational operation.

Your rotation can then be expressed as 2x2 matrix calculated from the unit vectors pointing from the origin to the starting point and to the current mouse point respectively.

*D*<sub>S</sub> = (*x*<sub>DS</sub>, *y*<sub>DS</sub>) = (S - O) / ||S - O||

*D*<sub>M</sub> = (*x*<sub>DM</sub>, *y*<sub>DM</sub>) = (M - O) / ||M - O||

[image]

> **Warning**
>
> We can calculate the inverse of the second matrix so easily because we know that the matrix is made out of an unit vector - and thus the determinant has the value of exactly **1**. This is *not* a generic formula for calculating such.

The resulting matrix can again be expressed as a unit vector of direction, in case you ever need it:

*D*<sub>R</sub> = (*x*<sub>DM</sub> *x*<sub>DS</sub> + *y*<sub>DM</sub> *y*<sub>DS</sub>, - *x*<sub>DM</sub> *y*<sub>DS</sub> + *y*<sub>DM</sub> *x*<sub>DS</sub>)

The rotation matrix describes a rotation about the origin (0, 0) - not about *your* origin. For this, the points first have to be moved so that the object origin is the same as world origin, rotated, then moved back to their original position. In other words:

*P*<sub>rotated</sub> = *R* x (*P*<sub>original</sub> - *O*) + *O*

You can express the translations as 3x3 matrices if you first extend your 2D vectors by an anonymous dimension with the constant value of 1 for all of them; the three transformations can then be pre-calculated into one single matrix by simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: An example in C#/XNA would be nice, not sure whether to (S - O) / (S-O) which is 0, or ((S-O) / S) - O or if it's just a variation of the first, still confused.

Comment: @Deukalion ||v|| is the mathematical notation for "length of vector *v*". In other words, calculate (S-O) (a vector), sum the squares of its elements, then calculate the square root of the sum.